# Extracting matches in NGiNX with regex without if block

Tags: nginx, regex

With NGiNX I get a string that contains information that I can extract content with regex.

But the only way I found that I could do this, is with if block. Is there any another way?

The extracted value needs to be set in a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can catch content to variable with PCRE named capture. It is well [described](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#regex_names) in the official Nginx doc.

Comment: That's for when you use server_name. I am trying to catch the value found in a string that as nothing to do with the domain name and is found in the location block.

Comment: No, it's not. Try such config:
 
 location ~ ^/foobar/(?<somenumbers>\d+) {
  return  200  "New link will be: http://somecoolsite.com/$somenumbers.jpeg\n";
  default_type text/plain;
 }